# how to group count items in SPARQL, accumulating low hit entries?

Tags: sparql

How do I count grouped entries in SPARQL, merging entries whose quantity is less than a specific factor?

Consider for example the [Nobel Prize data](http://data.nobelprize.org/snorql). I could get a count of all family names with a query like

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?name (count(*) as ?count) WHERE {
  ?id foaf:familyName ?name
}
GROUP BY $name
ORDER BY DESC($count)
```

How do I modify the query so it only returns the family names occuring at least 3 times, accumulating the other names as *other*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your `SELECT` into another one.

**Query**

```sql
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?name_ (SUM(?count) AS ?count_) {
  {
    SELECT ?name (COUNT(*) AS ?count) { 
      ?id foaf:familyName ?name
    } GROUP BY ?name
  }
  BIND (IF(?count > 2, ?name, "Other") AS ?name_)
} GROUP BY ?name_ ORDER BY DESC(IF(?name_ = "Other", -1 , ?count_))
```

**Results**

```
   name_       count_  
 ----------- --------- 
   Smith         5     
   Fischer       4     
   Wilson        4     
   Lee           3     
   Lewis         3     
   Müller        3     
   Other       878
```